# Compiling multiple .aux files with multibib?

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to have two separate bibliography, one for the main text, the other for the appendix. I use the following code. The file `Paper.bib` includes all my references.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{apndx}{Appendix References}

\bibliographystyle{ecca}
\bibliography{Paper}

\bibliographystyleapndx{ecca.bst}
\bibliographyapndx{Paper}

\end{document}
```

I use F11 to compile `Paper.aux` through `bibtex`. But how should I compile `apndx.aux` file through `bibtex`?

Comment: I use Texmaker. How should I use terminal/console?

Comment: OK. Got it. But it gives me errors like these:    bibtex apndx.aux
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: apndx.aux
I couldn't open style file ecca.bst.bst
---line 1 of file apndx.aux
 : \bibstyle{ecca.bst
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no \citation commands---while reading file apndx.aux
I found no style file---while reading file apndx.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Comment: I shouldn't have put .bst for style. Solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `.bst` you have to delete (see the marked line `<========` in the following code `mwe.tex`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{apndx}{Appendix References}

\bibliographystyle{ecca}
\bibliography{Paper}

\bibliographystyleapndx{ecca} % <====================================
\bibliographyapndx{Paper}

\end{document}
```

After completing the full cycle

```
pdflatex mwe.tex
bibtex mwe.aux
bibtex apndx.aux
pdflatex mwe.tex
pdflatex mwe.tex
```

you will get a pdf file compiled without errors ...

Answer (score 1):

For future reference; in Texmaker you need to go to "Tools" and "Open Terminal". Then type "bibtex apndx". This will give you .bbl file.