# Multiple bibliographies from multiple .bib files

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I have two different .bib files from which I want to create the corresponding bibliographies. One should be all the references made in the main text, while the second bibliography should be all the references made in the appendix. I've tried following [this example](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/multiple-bibliographies-with-multibib/fzmrrgbcvqhf) and changing the second .bib file reference, but TexMaker is not able to identify the correct citation (gives a ?).

So my setup should be like this:

Main text
Cite 1 and cite 2
Bibliography of citation 1 and 2
Appendix
Cite 1a
Bibliography of citation 1a

Where cite 1 and cite 2 are in one .bib file and cite 1a is another file. [One example](https://www.privacypies.org/blog/2017/01/25/bib-management.html) shows this with multibib, but it uses command lines with TexMaker, which I don't want.

How can I easily do this in TexMaker?

Comment: Are you using bibtex or biblatex? Both are in your tags, please clarify which one you use.

Comment: My apologies, I'm using bibtex.

Comment: Did you saw my answer in question https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396841/16550 ?